# Selenium Webdriver Facebook

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium web driver to click on the Facebook marketplace search bar. I spent hours trying to find, but can. This is what I have so far.  The html code for the search bar is provided below.I trained aria-label, @placeholder not search what to do from here.

My goal is to use find element by xpath and send keys.

```py
 self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Log In')]").click()
        sleep(10)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@aria-label="Marketplace"]').click()
        sleep(10)
        marketplace_button = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='Search Marketplace']").send_keys("acura tsx")
```

HTML

```html
 input dir="ltr" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-expanded="true" aria-label="Search Marketplace" role="combobox" placeholder="Search Marketplace" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" aria-invalid="false" class="x1i10hfl xggy1nq x1s07b3s x1kdt53j x1yc453h xhb22t3 xb5gni xcj1dhv x2s2ed0 xq33zhf xjyslct xjbqb8w xnwf7zb x40j3uw x1s7lred x15gyhx8 x972fbf xcfux6l x1qhh985 xm0m39n x9f619 xzsf02u xdl72j9 x1iyjqo2 xs83m0k xjb2p0i x6prxxf xeuugli x1a2a7pz x1n2onr6 x15h3p50 xm7lytj xsyo7zv xdvlbce x16hj40l xc9qbxq xo6swyp x1ad04t7 x1glnyev x1ix68h3 x19gujb8" type="search" value="" aria-controls=":r2t:"
```

Please refer to above comment. Many of my attempts have been using the HTML code Xpath. I also used Css selector.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.